# Algolia Real-time Webhooks

Tags: algolia

Is there any way to know whenever Algolia has successfully processed a queued job, or if Algolia has indexed new documents compared to the last re-index?

We'd like to build a system that whenever a new document is indexed, users browsing the website are warned in real-time of the update, and to go checkout the new stuff.

Is something like this possible?

If not, is there any workaround to make this possible?

Comment: Is this question related to the Algolia for Shopify integration ? If not, waiting for an Algolia job is as easy as using [`wait_task`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/indexing#wait-for-operations) with the `taskID` which is present in the response of the API to all indexing operations.

Comment: No, this is not a question for the Shopify integration, it's an in-house integration of Algolia in our closed source e-commerce. Using the `wait_task` however forces me to create a pooling timer to check if a job has completed. A Webhook would warn our servers directly instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're completely right, webhooks could definitely make sense. Unfortunately, Algolia doesn't provide such a feature, you'll have to rely on polling.

Jobs you send to Algolia are executed sequentially. A fairly easy solution would be to store in a queue each job with its associated action: you can have a dedicated process whose only role would be to infinitely wait on the first `taskID` of the queue and execute the action as soon as it returns.

Comment: We use Laravel in our company, and the solution you've proposed is extremely hard to accomplish in a clean way. Updates or additions to Algolia indexes are handled automatically through [AlgoliaEloquentTrait](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-laravel-4/blob/master/src/AlgoliaEloquentTrait.php) that automatically looks for updates and it pushes them over to the server. I can not access the `taskID` directly since it's an event.

Comment: Then I guess you're running into the limitations of the abstraction. Using the PHP client directly though, you'll have no issue achieving what you want, it'll just take a bit more time (https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/getting-started). You could also still try opening an issue on algoliasearch-laravel directly.